# Struggling with passing macro value in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Originally, I have the code like this.

```
data newFile;
set File;
   If Gender NE 'Female' then delete;
   If Group NE 10 then delete;
   If Age GT 30 then delete;
run;
```

It works just fine. But I want to be able to change those criteria from the top, so I add the macro variable. So far, I have this

```
&let macGender = 'Female';
&let macGroup = 10;
&let macAge = 30;

data newFile;
set File;
   If Gender NE &macGender then delete;
   If Group NE &macGroup then delete;
   If Age GT &macAge then delete;    
run;
```

It doesn't seem to work like the original's code. I even tried something like this

Answer (score 6):

You want `%let` rather than `&let`.

`%let` is the macro statement used to assign a value to a macro variable.

`&let` is a reference to a macro variable which you (probably) have not created.

Comment: Interestingly, it could work with &let if you did create it properly.  `%let let=%nrstr(%let);

%unquote(&let) let2=3;

%put &let2;
`  Not exactly practical but interesting!

Answer (score 1):

put % signs instead of & infront of you let statement and get rid of your quotes around female in your macro declaration.

Put those quotes around the actual macro.

For example

%let macGender = Female;

if Gender NE "&macGender." then delete;

Comment: Perhaps you could add a short explanation of why you don't think the quotation marks should be included in the macro variable assignment. As macro variables exclusively contain text and are here being used to modify data step code before it is evaluated both approaches will work the same.

Comment: I agree with not putting the quotes in the variable, but also agree with SRSwift that you should explain why this is a good idea.

Comment: Further, it would also be worth explaining the benefits of using double quotes as you have.